# Have ESC trigger a back event only when modal is visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onkeydown

So, I have a pure CSS modal window that I'm happy with; it's light and it's quick.  However, I would like to add some specific functionality that I believe can only be accomplished with javascript--namely, I want the escape key to trigger the disappearance of the modal and clicking on the overlay to do the same.

Being a pure css modal, it relies on the :target pseudo attribute, and therefore on the url.  So, I decided to try this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
evt = evt || window.event;
if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
history.go(-1);
}
};
```

However, by loading that in my document head, ESC triggers a back event regardless of whether the modal is on the screen.  I only want ESC to trigger a back event if pressed while the modal is visible.  *How do I accomplish that?*

By the way, the css for the modal changes the container `display` attribute from `none` to `block`.

```
.modalWrap {
    display:none;
    z-index:40001;
}
    #dbw.modalWrap:target {
        display: block;
    }
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="modalWrap" id="dbw">
    content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, I actually managed to find a solution:

```
window.document.onkeydown = function (e)
    {
        if (!e) e = event;
        if (e.keyCode == 27)
          var elem = document.getElementById("dbw");
            if (elem.currentStyle) {
                var displayStyle = elem.currentStyle.display;
            } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
                var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("display");
            }
        if (displayStyle != 'none') {
            history.go(-1);
        }
    }
```

On ESC press, the display style for the div with id "dbw" is retrieved, then, if it is not equal to `none`, the back event is triggered.  Tested and works flawlessly.

If someone does provide a cleaner, shorter code, then I will mark their answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    if (document.getElementById(modal_id).style.display != 'none') {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
            history.go(-1);
        }
    }
};
```

Evaluate if the `Modal` is on the screen with reference to its `display` property.

Comment: Hope It will charm as you want ;)

Comment: To my novice eyes, that definitely looks good and makes sense.  However, it isn't working.  I have a suspicion as to why; perhaps you can shed some light.  I've added the CSS above for you, and anyone else, to look at.

Comment: To be clear, what doesn't work is that ESC still triggers a back event regardless of whether the modal is visible.

Comment: I think the trouble with your code is that `if (document.getElementById(modal_id).style.display != 'none')` does not request the status of the display attribute.  It actually sets it and returns as true.

Comment: @David sorry buddy i have other work also to do that is why i can't reply. I saw that you got solution.

Comment: Aqib, I understand. Thanks for taking a shot at it.